# calling controller function from a link_to rails and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, controller

Trying to update some attributes into the database after i click on this link. I need the link to perform its original action and when its clicked calls a controller action to `update_attributes`.

- made a `get` and `post` route for the `/completed` url path.
- link_to is for downloading a file.
- What im trying to do: "when file is clicked/downloaded the db column gets updated". thats when the `updated attributes` gets called.
- When the link_to is clicked i want to update the attribute. I also want the link to do what it is currently doing which is to download a file.
- My problem is that im not being redirected to the `completed` `function` in my controller, when i click on the link.

HTML

```html
<% @reservations.where("turned_in = ?", true).where("completed_doc_updated_at <= due_date", true).each do |reservation| %>

    <div class="">
      <%= link_to_if(reservation.completed_doc_file_name, "Revised document", reservation.completed_doc.url(:original, false), :onClick => "window.location = '/completed'", class: "btn btn-download paperviewed") %>
        <% if reservation.completed_doc_file_name.blank?==false %>

          <div style="color:green;">
            sent
          </div>
          <% else %>

            <div style="color:red;">
              Not Sent
            </div>
            <% end %>
              <div class="">
                --->
              </div>

    </div>

<% end %>
```

RAILS CONTROLLER

```rails
def completed
    puts "hello"
    reservation.update_attributes completed: true
  end
```

ROUTES

```rails
post '/completed' => 'reservations#completed'
get '/completed' => 'reservations#completed'
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but sounds like you might be making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: You could set a debug in the html with <% binding.pry %> or debug, or you can open the console <%= console %> at any point, this way you can check the link_to_if and see every component value to understand the real problem 

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: oops okay i figured out a different solution to this problem, im on a new issue now :/ haha